Formularios Win Form C#
tengo una pequeña aplicación en win Form en C# Tengo un formulario Padre que carga en un panel los formularios hijos, el panel tiene de fondo una imagen, cuando los formularios hijos se cargan se ven pestañeos de la imagen de fondo del panel, la imagen desaparece por completo, solo aparece al llamar otro formulario hijo, agradecería me puedan ayudar
 // Método para abrir un formulario hijo dentro del panel

public void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, string titulo, FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar icono)
{
try
{
// Si ya hay un formulario hijo cargado en el panel, ciérralo y libéralo.
if (this.PanelContenedor.Controls.Count > 0)
{
var previousForm = (Form)this.PanelContenedor.Controls[0];
previousForm.Close();
previousForm.Dispose(); // Liberar recursos
this.PanelContenedor.Controls.Remove(previousForm);
}
     // Configuración del nuevo formulario hijo
     childForm.MdiParent = this; // Asignar el formulario principal como MdiParent
     childForm.TopLevel = false;
     childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     this.PanelContenedor.Controls.Add(childForm);
     this.PanelContenedor.Tag = childForm;
     childForm.BringToFront();
     childForm.Show();

     // Actualizar el título y el ícono
     ActualizarTitulo(titulo, icono);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al abrir el formulario: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }

}
// Eventos para botones
private void PrimerAño_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
ActivateButton(sender);
// Pasar la instancia actual del MainForm al constructor de FormPrimerAño
FormPrimerAño formPrimerAño = new FormPrimerAño(this);
OpenChildForm(formPrimerAño, "1er Año", FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.BookOpen);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al procesar el botón Primer Año: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
}
private void SegundoAño_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
ActivateButton(sender);
FormSegundoAño formSegundoAño = new FormSegundoAño(this);
OpenChildForm(formSegundoAño, "2do Año", FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.BookOpenReader);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al procesar el botón Segundo Año: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
}
private void TercerAño_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
ActivateButton(sender);
FormTercerAño formTercerAño = new FormTercerAño(this);
OpenChildForm(formTercerAño, "3er Año", FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.UserGear);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al procesar el botón Tercer Año: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
}
private void CuartoAño_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
ActivateButton(sender);
FormCuartoAño formCuartoAño = new FormCuartoAño(this);
OpenChildForm(formCuartoAño, "4to Año", FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.ChalkboardTeacher);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al procesar el botón Cuarto Año: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
}
private void QuintoAño_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
ActivateButton(sender);
FormQuintoAño formQuintoAño = new FormQuintoAño(this);
OpenChildForm(formQuintoAño, "5to Año", FontAwesome.Sharp.IconChar.UserGraduate);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al procesar el botón Quinto Año: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
}

Tienes que publicar el código para poder examinarlo y probarlo. Así como está planteado puede ser un millón de cosas.

Tu pregunta tiene muchos problemas.. primero y principal, las etiquetas deben ser acordes a la pregunta. ni js, ni asp.net ni siquiera .net son parte de tu problema. Segundo, eso que describis es el comportamiento correcto al usar winforms con una imagen de fondo, tenes que desactivar el doble buffer para que no pase, pero como no pusiste nada de codigo, es imposible ayudarte con lo que pasa.

buscar tambien conlleva unos buenos frutos...
